# Munin CGI Graphs (dynazoom) not working ootb on Centos 6.5

Tags: apache, centos, munin

Apologies if this is asked and answer but I've scoured the web and cannot find any info to help with this.

Basically I have Munin install on multiple centos 6.5 machines.  They all work well.  But the CGI graphics (when you select to view a specific chart to zoom in and stuff) do not.  All we see is a broken image.

The installs are all ootb with little to no modification.  There are a few errors in both Munin's and httpd's logs:

munin-cgi-graph.log:

```
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $dom in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph line 137.
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $host in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph line 137.
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $serv in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph line 137.
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $scale in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph line 137.
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $scale in pattern match (m//) at /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph line 139.
2014/10/15 10:41:05 [WARNING] Request for graph without specifying domain. Bailing out.
```

httpd error.log:

```
[Wed Oct 15 11:18:16 2014] [warn] [client 10.77.98.119] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Wed Oct 15 11:18:16 2014] [error] [client 10.77.98.119] Premature end of script headers: munin-cgi-graph
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: image/png
X-Munin-Pid: 24520
X-Munin-Request: 0/0
```

Now to call out this error seems to have changed since yesterday.  I did install mod_fcgid based on another forum and it still didn't work.  But it seems to have changed the error.

I'm hitting a wall with this stuff sadly.  I thought it would be easy (silly me!).  Any help would be totally brilliant!

Cheers,
Ryu.